# Showing Invalid date in input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to change the default date format to DD/MM/YYYY. I have successfully did this. But it showing invalid date. When I select a date it's work well. But when I clear the date it's shows Invalid Date. How can I remove this error message.

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
    this.setAttribute(
        "data-date",
        moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")
```

```css
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: black;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; left: 6px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" data-date="" placeholder="s" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY"  name="tckt_issue_date">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format[enter link description here][1]

Comment: This I have researched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The reason you were getting the invalid date error is because when you clear the date the input is passing an empty date to your jQuery function.  When the value is given to the `moment()` it returns an error because it expects a valid date.

So you need to test for an empty value.

Working code:

```js
$('#datePicker').on('change', function() {

      if(this.value){

        $(this).attr('data-date', moment(this.value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format($(this).attr('data-dateformat')));

      } else{

        $(this).attr('data-date', '');

      }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<input id="datePicker" type="date" data-date="" placeholder="s" data-dateformat="DD/MM/YYYY"  name="tckt_issue_date">
```

This code also properly updates the data-date attribute in the html.

Comment: Nope!  Have you?

Comment: @Mehedi Hasan Siam  Please see the updated answer.  Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

[This is already answered here you can can check.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Either you can change the format by jQuery or Javascript.

1. Get value from input via jQuery
2. Replace the this character `-` with `/` via jQuery string replace function
3. Then then finally assign it again to input value attribute value  `.attr(value, your-value);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how you can change the input field date format to DD/MM/YYYY

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
    this.setAttribute(
        "data-date",
        moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")
```

```css
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" data-date="" required placeholder="s" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" value="2015-08-09" name="tckt_issue_date">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please always explain your code, how does it answer the question? What did you do?